# i am facing an error interacting with server continuously in an android app

Tags: android

i have made an app which is running well, which is continuously sending user lat long to the server and also some other interaction with server(like profile image, name,friend list and all showing from server). but the problem is when app is in background/user make phonecall/user using another apps my apps loose its connection and user get out of the services retrieving from server(all service depends on user id which user get during log in). i am trying to solve this issue like my app will always be okay and interact with its server activity without any error or interruption for example facebook app do. how to make my network connection and manage which will behave like facebook or whatsApp app.
check image .first one is while app interacting well(with profile name and pic) and second one is while error (without profile name and pic) for example.

my asyncTaskClass:

```
public class GetPostAsyncTaskWithInterface extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public AsyncResult asyncResult;
//    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private final String baseUrl = UserInfo.getSiteUrl();

    public Context context=null;


    GetPostAsyncTaskWithInterface(Context context,AsyncResult asyncResult) {

        this.context=context;
        this.asyncResult= asyncResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Toast.makeText(context,"Loading..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            // setting the URL
            URL url = new URL(baseUrl+args[1]);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // setting the method type
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(args[0]);
//                httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            Log.v("Url", args[2]);
            // setting the identification key name with query params
            bufferedWriter.write(args[2]);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();

            Log.v("GetPostA", url.toString());

            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10*1000);
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 );

            httpURLConnection.connect();
            int getPostStatus = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            Log.v("GetPostSts", String.valueOf(getPostStatus));


            String line = "";
            String res = "";
//                if(getPostStatus == 200){

            // prepare the output buffer
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                res += line;

            }

            inputStream.close();

//                }

            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

//                Log.v("ResD", res.toString());
            return res.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("GetPostCatchMal",e.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("GetPostCatchIOE", e.toString());

        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
            try{
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
        if(result!=null) {
            asyncResult.asyncResult(result);
        }

    }

}
```

and my activity class is like:

```
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        context = NavigationDrawerActivity.this;

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);


        ownProfilePic = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.ownImageShowDrawerHeaderIvId_navigationDrawer);
        ownNameShow = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.showUserNameTvId_navigationDrawer);

        /******************************   own profile name and image show **************************  */

        ownNameShow.setText(UserInfo.getOwnProfileName());
//        new ImageDownloaderTask(ownProfilePic).execute(UserInfo.ownProfilePicUrl);
        Picasso.with(context).load(UserInfo.getOwnProfilePicUrl()).resize(100,100).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_show).error(R.drawable.profile_show).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(ownProfilePic);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        this.lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
        provider =lm.getBestProvider(criteria,false);
        location = this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        this.locationListener = new NavigationDrawerActivity();
        this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, locationListener);


        if (location != null) {
            setUpMapIfNeeded(location);
            updateUserLatLong(location);

        }
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.

        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

        //route
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    // option menu.......................option menu,.,
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer_option_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;

        }
        Location location = this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            setUpMapIfNeeded(location);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            return;
        }
        Location location = this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.v("DangerNotification","locN M"+location);
        if (location != null) {
            setUpMapIfNeeded(location);

            UserInfo.setLat(location.getLatitude());
            UserInfo.setLng(location.getLongitude());
            UserInfo.setLocation(location);
        }
        //setUpMapIfNeeded(location);

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Live_MapActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Driver", "anyFriend");

                UserInfo.setFriendsId(friendIds.optString(marker.getId()));
                startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(context, "You tracking " + marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.v("DangerNotification", "locN " + location);

        if (location != null && SharedPreference.getDefaults("ownUserId", context) != "0") {

            updateUserLatLong(location);
            //setUpMapIfNeeded(location);
            float speed = location.getSpeed();
            UserInfo.setSpeed(speed);

            UserInfo.setLat(location.getLatitude());
            UserInfo.setLng(location.getLongitude());
            UserInfo.setLocation(location);
        }
        userPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude());

        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userPosition,
                    12));
            mMap.setMapType(UserInfo.getMapType());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        boolean gps_enabled = false;
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        if (gps_enabled) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Gps enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

          /* *********************************************  Gps checking **********************************************************   */

        boolean gps_enabled = false;
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        if (!gps_enabled) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Gps Disable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

            /* ************************************************************************************************************ */

    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded(Location location) {

        //updateUserLatLong(location);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }

//        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
//        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);

        LatLng userPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude());

        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userPosition,
                    UserInfo.getZoomLevel()));

            mMap.setMapType(UserInfo.getMapType());

            userFriendsPos();

        }
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Maps Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.tracker.systechdigital.realtimetrackingandmonitoring/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Maps Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,

                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.

                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.tracker.systechdigital.realtimetrackingandmonitoring/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }




    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                client);


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void asyncResult(String result) {

    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

        ownNameShow.setText(UserInfo.getOwnProfileName());
//        new ImageDownloaderTask(ownProfilePic).execute(UserInfo.ownProfilePicUrl);
        Picasso.with(context).load(UserInfo.getOwnProfilePicUrl()).resize(100,100).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_show).error(R.drawable.profile_show).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(ownProfilePic);

        if (location != null) {
            setUpMapIfNeeded(location);
            updateUserLatLong(location);

        }
    }


}
```

please need help.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks were not designed to do this. They are mainly for tasks that take a one or two seconds. They can also lead to a lot of problems. For your code example for instance, you update the UI in onPostExecute, this can lead to a NullPointerExceptions, memory leaks for your Activity. So try avoid using that.

I would suggest you use a background [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Services are components that keep on running in the background and have better performance, exactly useful for your case.

You can also watch the Google Android Performance Tutorials [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtlRNNhane0&index=4&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE)

Comment: Souhaib Guitouni , can you please integrate above code in to service. i am unable to do so i guess