# duplicate entry: com/google/common/collect/package-info.class in android

Tags: android

surprisingly i am facing a error of duplicate entry after i upate my android studio 2.2.1 to 2.2.2. i have searched in google but there is no similar solution.

this is error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/collect/package-info.class
```

build.gradle(module:app):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.systechdigital.webadeal"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1'
    compile 'com.survivingwithandroid:weatherlib_okhttpclient:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

how to solve this. i googled a lot but no similar error or solution i found

Comment: Are you using any .jar libraries? if so please refer that too.

Comment: By the way, 1) Your Volley library is deprecated. 2) You likely do not need to compile all of the Google Play Services. You can leave the auth library if that is the only one you are using

Comment: i did not use any other jar @SanifSS

Comment: tried cleaning the project or restarted caches?

Answer (score 2):

I guess your `volley:library` is old ,That's why problem .Use latest version .

**Step 1**

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

**Step 2**

Downgrade version `com.google.android.gms:play`

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1' //9.6.1
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1' //9.6.1
```

Finally **Clean-Rebuild** Your Project .

**FYI**

Downgrade is not good practice . You can change your `buildToolsVersion` if you want to use `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0`

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

Comment: @AAA you can use `compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'`

Comment: okay i will let you know it works or not after try now @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @AAA Another point .If you will same problem then comment each `compile 'com.google.android.gms` dependencies for make sure purpose

Comment: i use gms auth for gmail log in. nothing else i use for

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: hi can you please favor me @Intellij Amiya

Comment: how can i make error free continuous network operation even phone call and app in background android? i know it can solved by service but i am unable to do this.i am using asynctask for network operation

Comment: worry about `even phone call` time. you can use #Service in android .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016509/i-am-facing-an-error-interacting-with-server-continuously-in-an-android-app

Comment: can you please specify how to do with service . above link is provided my code

Comment: you provided the link with IntentService . can you please help me with my code. i have done with asynctask so it will tough to change whole project. it will be my great pleasure if you please help me

Comment: amiya can you solve help me solving the error please?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594214/error-while-apps-in-background-and-retrieve-during-videoplay-in-textureview-insi

Comment: problem solved @Intellij Amiya . now struggling for attaching mediacontroller properly on textureview. can you help me on this please?

and Intellij Amiya may i be connected with you by any means please?

Comment: @AAA i don't have enough knowledge about `Media Controller ` . You can post this as question . i will check

Comment: i sent you friend req on facebook with imranrana id can you accept please?\

Comment: and ok. i will try myself on mediacontroller :)

Comment: i have posted the ques about mediacontroller, if you please check,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642418/how-can-i-integrate-mediacontroller-and-thumbnails-to-textureview-android

Comment: @AAA http://www.malmstein.com/blog/2014/08/09/how-to-use-a-textureview-to-display-a-video-with-custom-media-player-controls/

Comment: i saw it meanwhile but i could not find any solution from there. :(

Comment: can you help me on this issue please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377114/notification-click-event-best-way-to-show-activity-data-from-service-while-app