# how can i integrate mediacontroller and thumbnails to textureview android

Tags: android

i am trying to make a video play option in recyclerview adapter in my app i can successfully play video in textureview now i am trying to add mediacontroller and thumbnail in to textureview video . i have tried by googling but i couldnt do.please need help.

this is my textureview interface method implementation:

```
@Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(final SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

        try {
            if(mediaPlayer!=null) {

                final Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"));
                mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);

                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(context);
                mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);

                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

//                        mediaPlayer.start();


                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        mediaPlayer.reset();
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

    }
```